# Use a form to give title on another page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, cookies

I'm looking for help because i try to make a form with 8 text field with a saving in a cookie and i want that those text fields can be appear like a accordeon tab title in the other page. do you think it's possible?

All my pages work just on a lan network, it's to create an interface to control many VLC Player (first page : configure the name of 8 VLC players and in the second page each player take the name present in the text field)

Thank a lot

Comment: Developing a site for LAN is the same as for the web. You still need a web server. Regarding your question: yes that's easily done using JavaScript. Save form data in a cookie and on the other page put that data into the DOM after the page is loaded. (There's JS events for this.) Just give it a shot and ask on SO again if you have more specific questions.

Comment: Hello Thanks Hubert,
my capacity in this domain are very little, can you show me a script to see how it's run please

Thanks in advance